# Primordial elements of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

We were given the following problem in our Algebra class.

Let $V$ be a $K$-vector space (not necessarily finite dimensional), and fix a basis $(e_i)_{i \in I}$ of $V$. If $x = \sum \xi_ie_i \in V $, denote by $J(x) = \{ i \in I \mid \xi_i \neq 0 \}$, a finite subset of $I$.

Let $W$ be a subspace of $V$. A nonzero vector $ x \in W$ is called *primordial* with respect to the basis $(e_i)_{i \in I}$, if $J(x)$ is minimal with respect to the inclusion relation among the nonzero vectors in $W$ and at least one of the coefficient $\xi_i$ is $1$.

Let $(\lambda_j)_{j \in J}$ be a family of elements of the dual space $V^*$. Write $\alpha_{ij} = \lambda_j(e_i)$. For $x \in V$, if $x = \sum \xi_i e_i$, then $\lambda_j(x) = \sum \xi_i \alpha_{ij} $ for all $j \in J$. If $(\eta_j)_{j \in J} $ is a family of elements of $K$, we refer to

$$ (*) \sum_{i \in I} X_i \alpha_{ij} = \eta_j \qquad (j \in J) $$

as a system of linear equations. If $\eta_j = 0$ for all $j \in J$ then the system is said to be homogeneous. A finitely supported family $(\xi_i)_{i \in I}$ of elements of $K$ is said to be a solution to $(*)$ if $\sum_{i \in I} \xi_i a_{ij} = \eta_j $ for all $j \in J$.

The set of solutions of a homogeneous system forms a subspace of $K^{(I)}$, which we can identify with a subspace $W$ of $V$ via the basis $(e_i)_{i \in I}$ of $V$. Given the system $(*)$, we refer to

$$\sum_{i \in I} X_i a_{ij} + Y(-\eta_j) = 0 \quad (j \in J) $$
as the associated homogeneous system. We define a primordial solution of the system $(*)$ to be a primordial solution of its associated homogeneous sytem $(X_i = \xi_i)_{i \in I}, Y=1$.

Questions:

(1) Assume $J(x)$ is minimal among the nonzero vectors in $V$. Show that for $y \in V$, $J(y) \subset J(x)$ if and only if there is some $ \beta \in K$ such that $ y = \beta x$.

(2) Prove that every subspace $W$ of $V$ is spanned by the set of its primordial vectors.

(3) Assume $(*)$ admits at least one solution. Show that its associated homogeneous sytem admits at least one primordial solution.

Question (1) is the only one I can do right now: the reverse direction is obvious. For the forward direction, if $J(y) \subset J(x)$ then $J(y) = J(x)$ and if $y$ is not a multiple of $x$ then we can find an appropriate multiplier $\gamma \in K$ such that $J(y-\gamma x) \neq \emptyset $ is strictly contained in $J(x)$, contradicting minimality of $J(x)$.

For question (2), I think I can prove it by induction on $|J(y)|$ for $y \in W$. Clearly, it's true for any multiple of a primordial vector in $W$, which I think is the base case, but how do I proceed?

Question (3) looks simple but I'm not sure I understand the definition of a primordial solution of the system. Does $Y=1$ satisfy the condition that one of the coordinates is $1$?

I think my problem is that I don't quite get the idea behind primordial vectors. I know that this is the generalization of solving $m$ linear equations in $n$ variables but it's all quite abstract. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You did not define $S(x)$ if I didn't miss anything.

Comment: Sorry I mean $J(x)$. Let me edit the question.

Comment: Now you mean $\xi_i$, not $\alpha_i$, I think, in the definition of $J$. (Sorry for the pedantry, there's just a lot of notation and it's hard to follow with errors).

Comment: Yes, I just fixed that too...

Comment: I guess my problem is also the fact that there's just so much preliminaries, and it's hard to keep them straight.